# LINQ Group By Join

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm struggling with what is a rather simple SQL select statement. How can this be translated into LINQ?

```
select 
    o.IdOrder, Date, s.suma, name, adresa
from 
    Clients c 
join 
    Orders o on (c.IdClient = o.IdClient)
join 
    (select IdOrder, sum(price) suma
     from OrderProduct
     group by IdOrder) s on (o.IdOrder = s.IdOrder);
```

If you could point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

This is what I have so far:

```
var y = from w in db.OrderProducts
        group w by w.IdOrder into TotaledOrder
        select new
                {
                    IdOrder = TotaledOrder.Key,
                    price = TotaledOrder.Sum(s => s.price)       
                };

var i = 0;
var cc = new dynamic[100];

foreach (var item in y)
{
    cc[i++] = db.Orders.Where(t => t.IdOrder == item.IdOrder)
            .Select(p => new
            {
                IdOrder = item.IdOrder,
                price = item.price,
            }).Single();
}
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. And you should **most definitely** not **MIX** the two styles! Just dump the comma-separated table in your `FROM` clause once and for all times, and use the proper ANSI JOIN syntax

Comment: Thank you, I changed the SQL. However, I still can' t figure out how to put that into LINQ

Comment: Still bad - there should be a `join` (or `inner join`) between the `Orders o` and the subquery aliased with a `s` .... (like between `Clients` and `Orders`)

Comment: Much better now !

Comment: I suppose this is how I should go about the LINQ code also. Forget about the for each and the where clause and use multiple joins?

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL doesn't really give an idea on your underlying structure. By a guess on column names:

```
var result = from o in db.Orders
             select new {
                  IDOrder = o.IDOrder,
                  Date = o.Date,
                  Suma = o.OrderProduct.Sum( op => op.Price),
                  Name = o.Client.Name,
                  Adresa = o.Client.Adresa
             };
```

(I have no idea what you meant by the loop in your code.)

Comment: Sorry about the lack of information I provided. 4 tables, Clients with the following columns: IdClient, name, adresa;  Orders: IdOrder, Date, IdClient (FK), Products: IdProduct, price, name and OrderProducts(associative between Orders and Products): IdOrder, IdProduct, price, quantity.

Comment: @Cristina, Then the answer is correct. If you like, I can give the same sample code using Northwind sample database as the source (if your backend is MS SQL). BTW, probably what you want is the sum of quantity * price instead of just price.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it from here